# Rails web service not returning required response

Tags: android, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

I am newbie to rails and currently trying to build a REST api on Rails.I am trying to connect to the rest web service from my android app.
This is the controller code that i am routing the request to.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:userid],
                             params[:password])
    if user.nil?
      message="Invalid Username/Password"
      return message
    else
      sessionId=make_sessionId
      return sessionId
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

I am trying to hit the create action in the SessionController.The problem is that the response i get is the html of the view whereas what i am looking forward to is the '*message* or the '*sessionId*' from the controller.I deleted the view files after which i am getting the html with exceptions inside it.

Can someone let me know what i should here to get the response from the controller rather than returning the html inside the view at the client.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no render in your Controller, then rails will use the view related to the action name. Try "render :text => message" for example. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: So you mean that if i use render :text => message instead of 'return message' in the above code I will get the required response from the web service?Do i need to add anything more?

Sorry not at workplace now so cannot try it right away.

Comment: Give it a try. I never used android. I hope it works :-) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: I don't think it would matter whatever the client is.

Comment: Thanks Bjoernsen.This was exactly what i wanted.Learned a new thing and it worked.